# SQLITE3 INSERT command fails on older version

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu-12.04

The likely reflects my ignorance on sqlite mechanics, but the following sqlite3 code seems to work on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo(name STRING);
sqlite> INSERT OR IGNORE INTO foo (name) VALUES ("a");
sqlite> INSERT OR IGNORE INTO foo (name) VALUES ("a"), ("b");
```

Now, using a machine with Ubuntu 12.04, I run the same commands and the last line fails with:

```
sqlite> INSERT OR IGNORE INTO foo (name) VALUES ("a"), ("b");
Error: near ",": syntax error
```

Looking at the [`INSERT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) syntax, I don't see anything wrong with adding a second item with a comma. What did I do wrong, or how can I fix this? Currently I'm stuck using:

```
> sqlite3 --version
3.7.9 2011-11-01 00:52:41 c7c6050ef060877ebe77b41d959e9df13f8c9b5e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting multiple records at once is supported in [SQLite 3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html) which you are unfortunately not using.

If you update your SQLite version then your query should run just fine.

Comment: Thanks! For future visitors, the obvious followup question on how to upgrade to the newer version of SQLite on Ubuntu is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/496486/how-to-install-sqlite-sqlite-3-7-11-on-ubuntu-12-04